# Compatibility shim used by .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

Overviews ([example](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/whats-new-in-net-standard-2/)) of .NET Standard 2.0 say that it now uses some kind of compatibility shim that fixes the third-party library compatibility issue. So you can use the third-party library with .NET Standard until it doesn't use any API which .NET Standard doesn’t have.

What is not clear is

- how does this shim work? any drawbacks?

and

- how to check that third-party library is supported? By directly adding it into the project and then trying to compile?

Comment: @leppie Comments are not for answers :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This works by creating all the necessary libraries that are referenced by classic .NET libraries.

E.g. in .NET Core the implementation of `Object` or `Attribute` is defined in `System.Runtime`. When you compile code, the generated code always references the assembly and the type => `[System.Runtime]System.Object`. Classic .NET projects however reference `System.Object` from `mscorlib`. When trying to use a classic .NET assembly on .NET Core 1.0/1.1, this usually leads to types not being found. In .NET Core 2.0, there will be "fake" types in a `mscorlib` that the runtime knows how to forward to where the implementation actually is.

You can read more about how this [assembly unification works on the dotnet/standard GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/tree/master/docs/planning/netstandard-2.0) but the most important scenario is this (image taken from this repository):

[image: mscorlib facade]

This shows how the scenario is supposed to work: When a 3rd party dll references `[mscorlib]Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`, there will be an `mscorlib.dll` that contains a type forward to `[Microsoft.Win32.Registry] Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` so it will work when a `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.dll` is present.

This also shows the major downside: The registry is a windows-only concept and not available on Mac or Linux so this particular code may fail to run on non-windows platforms. But if you use only parts of the library that do not use this functionality, it may work for cross-platform scenarios.

Another problem is that even if API is "available" to compile against and reference, it still may throw a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

For example, a library that implements a file format for serialisation / deserialisation might work without modification, even if it has been built for .NET Framework 3.5.

To find what API functions a particular library uses, the [.NET Portability Analyzer](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-apiport) can be used to scan a dll and show if the library is compatible and if not, which APIs are blocking.

Comment: How would I notice if a referenced .NET Framework library seems to be compatible with .NET Standard or not? Is it a compile-time error or a runtime-error?