# Confused about .NET Standard vs .NET Core "interface vs implementation" explanations

Tags: .net, xamarin, uwp, .net-core, .net-standard

**Context**

Although I understand that .NET Standard is a specification. I also understand that platforms (like .Core or Xamarin or UWP) conforms ("implements", "supports")  picked version of .NET standard say 1.4 or 1.6. I also understand the .NET standard versions compatibility order.

**Question**

If I create a .NET Standard class lib in Visual Studio, and add some references, and compile it, then that particular compiled assembly must reference to  concrete particular assemblies in a particular platform. However this way this assembly bound to that platform, this makes no sense.

So there must be a less hard "reference" metadata, this compiled assembly's references must be satisfied different assemblies (with the same strong name?)
in different platform implementations, where the my assembly is about to run.

With all cloudy explanation what I miss really the explanation: How is this works in practice? The theory and analogies seem to be clear.

Missing I something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All assemblies are compiled against a set of reference assemblies. This is true for all project types including .NET Standard, .NET Core and .NET Framework (and everything else.. except .NET <=3.5, but let's ignore that for simplicity).

.NET Standard defines a set of reference assemblies for each version that are used to compile .NET Standard assemblies against.

For .NET Standard 2.0, the most notable reference assembly is `netstandard.dll`. If you reference `System.Object`, the compiler will emit IL code referencing `[netstandard]System.Object`.

Any platform that "conforms" to .NET Standard 2.0 then has an implementation assembly `netstandard.dll` that either contains the type or contains type forwarding definitions. So for .NET Framework, there can be a `netstandard.dll` that contains a type forward to `[mscorlib]System.Object`. Another platform may have a different `netstandard.dll` that for instance forwards to `[System.Runtime]System.Object`.

In addition to `netstandard.dll` there are a few more libraries that are there to support .NET Standard 1.0-1.6 and a few other type forwarding dlls that form a compatibility shim for .NET Framework applications (See [Compatibility shim used by .NET Standard 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464937/compatibility-shim-used-by-net-standard-2-0/44492663#44492663) for an explanation).

There is also some tooling in place to actually allow .NET Standard assemblies being used on platforms that do not contain these forwarding assemblies. The `NETStandard.Library` NuGet package contains these for 1.0-1.6 and a new integrated MSBuild tooling adds support DLLs for .NET Framework 4.6.1+ for .NET Standard 1.5-2.0. .NET Framework 4.7.1 contains all the necessary assemblies so .NET Framework 4.7.1 projects do not need to add additional files to use .NET Standard assemblies.

Comment: Thanks. What is "type forwarding definition" or "type forwarding" ? Is that a wrapper class or a runtime trick instead ?

Comment: That's an IL feature: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr/2009/09/30/type-forwarding/

Comment: Some gems are still waiting to explore... More interestingly it is pretty old stuff. I've missed it so far.